# Merging Two Sorted Arrays

Tags: java, array-merge

So the question is: 
Given two sorted integer arrays nums1 and nums2, merge nums2 into nums1 as one sorted array.

Note:

The number of elements initialized in nums1 and nums2 are m and n respectively.

You may assume that nums1 has enough space (size that is greater or equal to m + n) to hold additional elements from nums2.

Example:

Input:

nums1 = [1,2,3,0,0,0], m = 3

nums2 = [2,5,6],       n = 3

Output: [1,2,2,3,5,6]

It gave me an indexOutOfBoundException but I have a hard time seeing which part of my logic is incorrect.

```
public void merge(int[] nums1, int m, int[] nums2, int n) {
        int aIndex = m--; // num1 pointer
        int bIndex = n--; // nums2 pointer;
        int mergeIndex = nums1.length - 1; //mergePointer

        while(mergeIndex >=  0) {
            if(aIndex < 0) {
                nums1[mergeIndex] = nums2[bIndex];
                bIndex--;   
            }
            else if (bIndex < 0) {
                nums1[mergeIndex] = nums1[aIndex];
                aIndex--;
            }
            else {
                if(nums1[aIndex] > nums2[bIndex]) {
                    nums1[mergeIndex] = nums1[aIndex];
                    aIndex--;
                }
                else {
                    nums1[mergeIndex] = nums2[bIndex];
                    bIndex--;
                }
            }
            mergeIndex --;

        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the input to this method? What are `m` and `n`?

Comment: The number of elements initialized in nums1 and nums2 are m and n respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is in the way you initialize `aIndex` and `bIndex`. You assign them `m` and `n` and then you decrease them (post decrement). That's why it gives you `ArrayOutOfBoundException`

Try this instead:

```
int aIndex = --m; // num1 pointer
int bIndex = --n; // nums2 pointer;
```

Comment: Got it! So if m = 5, the code m-- would display aIndex = 5 then decrement it, while --m would display aIndex as 4. Is what I'm getting correct?

Comment: Why decrement m and n? `int aIndex = m-1;
        int bIndex = n-1;
        int mergeIndex = m+n-1;` (because `nums1.length` can be greater than `m+n`).